# Phonegap deviceready not responding/firing

Tags: android, cordova

I am writing a mobile application for storing data locally using Sqlite. For the past 4 days, I have been trying to figure out why database is not creating when Jquery and phonegap are fully loaded. Create statement in sqlite doesn't work and callback functions are not working. The deviceready doesn't work but if checking for sqlite support it fires. The example code is someone's else code but the same thing happened. Can someone please help me?

```
var jqmReady = $.Deferred(),
pgReady = $.Deferred();

// jqm page is ready
$(document).bind("pageinit", jqmReady.resolve);

// phonegap ready
document.addEventListener("deviceready", pgReady.resolve, false);

// all ready, throw a custom 'onDeviceready' event
$.when(jqmReady, pgReady).then(function(){
  $(document).trigger("onDeviceready"); 
});


function onDeviceReady(){
        db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
    }

    //create table and insert some record
    function populateDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SoccerPlayer (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Name TEXT NOT NULL, Club TEXT NOT NULL)');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO SoccerPlayer(Name,Club) VALUES ("Alexandre Pato", "AC Milan")');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO SoccerPlayer(Name,Club) VALUES ("Van Persie", "Arsenal")');
    }

    //function will be called when an error occurred
    function errorCB(err) {
        alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
    }
    //function will be called when process succeed
    function successCB() {
        alert("success!");
        db.transaction(queryDB,errorCB);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't run it on an emulator or physical device but from looking at the code I can see one issue right off the back. Try this and see if it helps:

Change

```
$.when(jqmReady, pgReady).then(function(){
     $(document).trigger("onDeviceready"); 
});
```

to

```
$.when(jqmReady, pgReady).then(function(){
     onDeviceReady();
});
```

The reason I suggest that change is because `$(document).trigger("onDeviceready")` is triggering the 'onDeviceready' event. You don't have a listener setup to catch that event and I assume what you wanted it to do is call the "onDeviceReady()" function.

Comment: Thank you Jeffery, i followed your instruction and it worked.